# PHP and MySQL: Number of rows returned

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-num-rows

How can I see how many rows the following query returns?

```
mysql_select_db($database_aoldatabase, $aoldatabase);

$query1 = "select * from sale where secid  = $invoiceno ";
$query2 = "select * from sale where secid  = $invoiceno ";


$maxa = mysql_query ($query1)
    or die ("Query '$query' failed with error message: \"" . mysql_error () . '"');
$maxa2 = mysql_query ($query2)
    or die ("Query '$query' failed with error message: \"" . mysql_error () . '"');

$row = mysql_fetch_array($maxa);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($maxa2);
```

Answer (score 7):

Like Michiel said, `mysql_num_rows()` do the job. But if you want to work with more than one rows using an array, you can use `count()` too.

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($maxa, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
$count1 = mysql_num_rows($maxa);
$count2 = count($data);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the function `mysql_num_rows()`

Have a look at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: `$numrows = mysql_num_rows($maxa);` :) +1