# PHP: How to check if no rows are returned

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

With the following PHP code, how do i check if there's no row retuned so i can echo some message?

PHP:

```
<?php 
    require_once 'db_conx.php';
    $Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE pid = '2'")
        or die (mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)){
        echo '<span class="classPid" style="display:none">'.$row['pid'].'</span>';
    }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP and MySQL: Number of rows returned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140298/php-and-mysql-number-of-rows-returned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
<?php 
    require_once 'db_conx.php';
    $Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE pid = '2'")
        or die (mysql_error());
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)){
        echo "<span class='classPid' style='display:none'>".$row['pid']."</span>";
        $i++;
    }
    if($i==0){
        echo "No rows found";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why didn't you suggest `mysql_num_rows`?

Comment: @Console, Calling a `function` is quite expensive.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Simple and short, what do you mean functions are expensive?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to do this. There is a specific function `mysql_num_rows()` which will return the number of rows returned.

```
mysql_num_rows($Result);
```

This will return `0` if there are no rows affected or returned.

You could also create some conditions using `mysql_fetch_array`. `mysql_fetch_array` will return `FALSE` if there are no rows.

> On a separate note it would be a good idea to update your connection
>   and functions to `mysqli` as `mysql` is no depreciated.

See docs on `mysql_num_rows()`.

http://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows

Comment: That's a good answer too, but you know the JQuery generation always goes for short solutions.

Comment: This is the best approach but mysql_num_rows($Result); has been deprecated and removed since PHP 7.0
Instead use:

    mysqli_num_rows()  OR   
    mysqli_stmt_num_rows()  OR   
    PDOStatement::rowCount()  
See the linked PHP documents for details.

@Dane Caswell, I'll leave any editing to you. Due to SOs SEO this answer is still a top Google hit.